# How to add a return button in Struts

Tags: java, mapping, struts

I am very new to Struts, I have 3 pages(page 1,page 2,page 3).My concern is to get back back from page 3 to page 2.I have added a return button in page 3 to go to the previous page & the logic I have written for that is `mapping.findforward("doRefresh");`, 
my global forward is referencing to an action url which is associated with my page 2.But some how it is going to first page.Any idea why?...

Comment: please post some code.

Comment: the referenced action is not working